# How do i add to a List<long> another array long?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Im doing this:

```
long[] HistogramValues = Form1.GetHistogram(bitmap);
Form1.Histograms.AddRange(HistogramValues);
```

But then Histograms contain also 256 values like HistogramValues.
I want that in Histograms in index [0] there will be 256 values from HistogramValues then in [1] also 256 values then [2] and so on.

Histograms is a List

Comment: So, essentially you want an array of lists?

Comment: Prayos yes. Thats what i want in general.

Comment: No. If "Histograms is a List", you want a list of arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a list of arrays

```
List<long[]> Histograms = new List<long[]>();
```

And then add the arrays

```
long[] HistogramValues = Form1.GetHistogram(bitmap);
Form1.Histograms.Add(HistogramValues);
```

Comment: Bernd you right i will mark answer in 10 minutes i cant now its saying in 10 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A list of array of longs - `List<long[]>`

```
class Form1
{
    public Form1()
    {
         this.Histograms = new List<long[]>();
    }

    public List<long[]> Histograms { get; private set; }
}

long[] histogramValues = Form1.GetHistogram(bitmap);
Form1.Histograms.Add(histogramValues);
```

Then you can access each histogram as such:

```
long[] fifthHistogram = Form1.Histograms[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a 2-dimensional array or nested Lists:

```
long[,] longArray = new long[16, 256];
List<List<long>> longList = new List<List<Long>>();
```

For the array you will have 16 columns each with 256 values. For the List implementation you can add as many as you want...likely `longList[0] = new List<long>(256)` for your case but these lists are not bound in anyway.

**Additional Resources:**

[MSDN Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)